# Temperatures subtraction

Tags: arithmetic

Today I was solving this question: 
The high temperature on April 4 was $6$ $C^\circ$ The high temperature on April 5 was $-2C^\circ$ What was the difference in temperatures?

And my teacher said the answer is -8 but I think it is +8.
Who is right?why?

Comment: Please do not ask the same question twice. If you needed more feedback or a better answer than the one you accepted here https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2649237/temperatures-differences-subtraction you should have edited that question.

Answer (score 0):

The difference in temperature will be $$\Delta \rm T= T_{final}-T_{initial}=(-2)-(6)=-8$$

The "-" sign shows that there is decrease in the value of temperature.

Though, absolute difference will be $8$.

Answer (score 0):

Either answer can be right. It depends on the context.

In a math class the official definition of "difference", which is what your teacher wants, is
$$
\text{recent value} - \text{older value} = (-2) - (6) = -8.
$$
I hope there was some discussion of this in class before you were asked the question.

You are thinking about the absolute value. In everyday language it would be perfectly reasonable to say "It was $8$ degrees colder on April $5$th than the day before." It would be a somewhat pedantic, but correct, to say "The April $5$th temperature changed $-8$ degrees from the day before."

Comment: @amWhy I don't usually answer duplicate questions. This one wasn't flagged that way when asked - the OP's other question I linked to was slightly different, and the answer there didn't answer this one. That said, I probably shouldn't have spent my time trying to teach in a situation where learning was unlikely.